ExceptionHandler is registered but never entered on occuring Exception
I have a net8 Microservice written in c#.
I want to use the IExceptionHandler Middleware but the Handler ist never called and the exception is returned to the Endpoint-Call.
The Handler:
public class GlobalExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{

    public async ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(HttpContext httpContext, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var statusCode = exception.GetStatusCode();

        httpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;

        var message = (exception.Message.EndsWith('"') && exception.Message.StartsWith('"'))
            ? exception.Message
            : $"\"{exception.Message}\"";

        await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(message, cancellationToken);

        return true;
    }
}

The Startup:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    #region REST
    services
        .AddControllers(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add<ModifyIdActionFilter>();
            options.Conventions.Add(new ApiConventions());
        })
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
        });
    services.AddExceptionHandler<GlobalExceptionHandler>();
    services.AddProblemDetails();
    #endregion
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{   
    #region Routing & Middleware
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseExceptionHandler();
    #endregion
}

What am I missing?

Problem solved.
I accidentally overwrote the exception handler with
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

I need to make sure that
app.UseExceptionHandler();

is called AFTER
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

